# Understanding and Using a Context

Tags: android, android-widget, android-layout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is Context in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572463/what-is-context-in-android)

everyone! Can someone please explain to me what exactly is a Context in Android??? I don't understand the definition on the android developers website and I have to use them for a GridView Layout.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.